# Looking for origins of Johan Balthasar Bott from Mosbach, Baden, Germany?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, 18th-century, denmark, baden-wuerttemberg

Johan Balthasar Bott was a master tailor in Denmark in the 1800s. He married Kirstine Sophie Stephensen in 1834 in Nykobing Falster, Maribo, Denmark. I'm told that when he was married he signed an official document that mentioned (among other things) that he was born around 1791 in Mosbach, Baden, Germany.

I can't find any kind of record of his birth, his parents, or his family before Denmark.

Is there any resource where I could find that information?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Genealogy.SE! Please list the documents you have on Mr Bott.

Comment: Do you know the purpose of the "official document"? Was it to support his application to marry or for religious conversion, or related to citizenship, or to his guild association or master status, etc. Whether it might still be accessible would depend on where it might have been archived. You could verify what was actually written and see if there were any other names & dates that would make a search in German records easier. Bott does not sound like a south-German surname; at http://ofb.genealogy.net, Bott individuals are found in several Hessen databases (Greifenstein, Edingen, Wabern).

Answer (score 4):

Please note that [there are several places in southwestern Germany named “Mosbach”](http://gov.genealogy.net/search/name?name=Mosbach), I'll refer to the largest town (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosbach):

Catholic church records are available on microfilm from FamilySearch: [Kirchenbuch, 1688-1900](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/256024?availability=Family%20History%20Library), this is probably the best place to start. Sooner or later lutheran church records might be available on [Archion](https://www.archion.de/).

There is a local genealogy society named [VHS-Arbeitskreis Genealogie und Heraldik Mosbach/Baden](http://www.vhs-mosbach.de/akgen/index.htm), they offer [an overview on sources for Mosbach](http://www.vhs-mosbach.de/akgen/quellen/mosquel.htm). They also link newspaper articles about their activities for foreign researchers, maybe they will help you too.